# Grabbing value from piped file contents

Tags: awk

Let's say I have the following file:

```
credentials:
  [default]
  key_id = AKIAGHJQTOP
  secret_key = alcsjkf
  [default2]
  key_id = AKIADGHNKVP
  secret_key = njprmls
```

I want to grab the value of [default] key_id. I'm trying to do it with `awk` command but I'm open to any other way if it's more efficient and easier. Instead of passing a file name to `awk`, I want to pass the file contents from environmental variable `FILE_CONTENTS`

I tried the following:

```
$export VAR=$(echo "$FILE_CONTENTS" | awk '/credentials.default.key_id/ {print $2}')
```

But it didn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `credentials.default.key_id` is not a string available in input.

Comment: @anubhava sorry, I think my example was not correct, the file contains multiple `key_id` and I'm trying to grab the [default] one. I just updated my example, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Recognize section headers, populate awk variables from them, check for whether those variables match the values you expect _in addition to_ the line you're currently reading having the key you expect. Or, much better, give up on using awk and find a proper parser for the config file format at hand -- does the software that reads that config file use a 3rd-party library to parse it? Then use that same library yourself. You'll come away with a far less fragile solution that way.

Comment: ...hand-built parsers very often get things wrong; different config formats have different comment styles, different quoting/escaping rules, etc etc. It's easy to write something that works for the config file you have right now but fails for a differently-formatted, equally-valid config file.

Comment: how is `FILE_CONTENTS` populated and what does its contents look like (ie, what's the output from `typeset -p FILE_CONTENTS`)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` like this:

```bash
cat srch.awk

BEGIN { FS = " *= *" }
{ sub(/^[[:blank:]]+/, "") }
/:[[:blank:]]*$/ {
   sub(/:[[:blank:]]*$/, "")
   k = $1
}
/^[[:blank:]]*\[/ {
   s = k "." $1
}
NF == 2 {
   map[s "." $1] = $2
}
key in map {
   print map[key]
   exit
}

# then use it as
echo "$FILE_CONTENTS" |
awk -v key='credentials.[default].key_id' -f srch.awk

AKIAGHJQTOP

# or else
echo "$FILE_CONTENTS" |
awk -v key='credentials.[default].secret_key' -f srch.awk

alcsjkf
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- no spaces between labels and `:`
- no spaces between `[` the stanza name and `]`
- all lines with attribute/value pairs have exactly 3 space-delimited fields as shown (ie, `attr` `=` `value`; `value` has no embedded spaces)
- the contents of OP's variable (`FILE_CONTENTS`) is an exact copy (data and format) of the sample file provided by OP

**NOTE:** if the input file format can differ from these assumptions then additional code must be added to address said differences; as mentioned in comments ... writing your own parser is doable but you need to insure you address all possible format variations

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -v label='credentials' -v stanza='default' -v attr='key_id' '
/:/             { f1=0; if ($0 ~ label ":")      f1=1 }
f1 && /[][]/    { f2=0; if ($0 ~ "[" stanza "]") f2=1 }
f1 && f2 && /=/ { if ($1 == attr) { print $3; f1=f2=0 } }
'
```

This generates:

```
AKIAGHJQTOP
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v RS='(^|\\n)credentials:\\n[[:space:]]+\\[default\\]\\n[[:space:]]+key_id = \\S+' '
RT && num=split(RT,arr," key_id = "){
  print arr[num]
}
'   Input_file
```

Here is the [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/X7qHLu/1) for used regex(its bit changed from regex used in `awk` code as escaping is done in program not in site).

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'f{print $3; exit} /\[default]/{f=1}' <<<"$FILE_CONTENTS"
AKIAGHJQTOP
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to provide more truly realistic sample input/output including cases where the above doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> open to any other way if it's more efficient and easier

I suggest taking look at python's [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html), which is part of standard library. Let FILE_CONTENTS environment variable be holding

```
credentials:
  [default]
  key_id = AKIAGHJQTOP
  secret_key = alcsjkf
  [default2]
  key_id = AKIADGHNKVP
  secret_key = njprmls
```

then create file `getkeyid.py` with content as follows

```
import configparser
import os
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read_string(os.environ["FILE_CONTENTS"].replace("credentials","#credentials",1))
print(config["default"]["key_id"])
```

and do

```
python3 getkeyid.py
```

to get output

```
AKIAGHJQTOP
```

Explanation: I retrieve string from environmental variable and replace `credentials` with `#credentials` at most `1` time in order to comment that line (otherwise parser will fail), then parse it and retrieve value corresponding to desired key.